# A way to communicate to a Pod that it's restarting

Tags: kubernetes

I need to communicate to a Pod if it's restarting or not. Because depending of the situation my app is working differently (stateful app). I wouldn't like to create other pod that runs a kind of watchdog and then informs my app if it's restarting or not (after a fault). But maybe there is a way to do it with Kubernetes components (Kubelet,..).

Comment: How reliable do you need it to be?  You can set a [pre-stop hook](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-lifecycle-hooks/), but it won't fire if the container exits normally or if the node it's on is destroyed without warning.

Comment: @DavidMaze 100% reliable ... Your solution seems to be good because I would like this behaviour only for faulty containers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting from Kubernetes Docs:

1. > Processes in containers inside pods can also contact the apiserver.
   >   When they do, they are authenticated as a particular Service Account
   >   (for example, default)
2. > A RoleBinding or ClusterRoleBinding binds a role to subjects. Subjects can be groups, users or ServiceAccounts.
3. > An RBAC Role or ClusterRole contains rules that represent a set of
   >   permissions.
   >
   > A Role always sets permissions within a particular namespace.
   >
   > ClusterRole, by contrast, is a non-namespaced resource

So, In-order to get/watch the status of the other pod, you can call Kubernetes API from the pod running your code by using serviceaccounts. Follow below steps in-order to automatically retrieve other pod status from a given pod without any external dependency (Due to reliability concerns, you shouldn't rely upon nodes)

Create a serviceaccount in your pod's (requestor pod) namespace

```
kubectl create sa pod-reader
```

If both pods are in same namespace, create role,rolebinding

> Create a role
>
> ```
> kubectl create role pod-reader --verb=get,watch --resource=pods
> ```
>
> Create a rolebinding
>
> ```
> kubectl create rolebinding pod-reader-binding --role=pod-reader --serviceaccount=<NAMESPACE>:pod-reader
> ```

Else, i.e the pods are in different namespaces, create clusterrole,clusterrolebinding

> Create a clusterrole
>
> ```
> kubectl create clusterrole pod-reader --verb=get,watch --resource=pods
> ```
>
> Create a rolebinding
>
> ```
> kubectl create clusterrolebinding pod-reader-binding --clusterrole=pod-reader --serviceaccount=<NAMESPACE>:pod-reader
> ```

Verify the permissions

```
kubectl auth can-i watch pods --as=system:serviceaccount:<NAMESPACE>:pod-reader
```

Now deploy your pod/(your app) with this serviceaccount.

```
kubectl create <MY-POD> --image=<MY-CONTAINER-IMAGE> --serviceaccount=pod-reader
```

This will mount serviceaccount secret token in your pod, which can be found at `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token`. Your app can use this token to make GET requests to Kubernetes API server in-order to get the status of the pod. See below example (this assumes your pod has curl utility installed. However, you can make a relevant API call from your code, pass the Header by reading the serviceaccount token file mounted in your pod).

```
TOKEN=$(cat /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token)

curl https://kubernetes.default/api/v1/namespaces/<NAMESPACE>/pods/<NAME_OF_THE_OTHER_POD> -H "Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}" -k

curl https://kubernetes.default/api/v1/watch/namespaces/<NAMESPACE>/pods/<NAME_OF_THE_OTHER_POD>?timeoutSeconds=30 -H "Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}" -k
```

References:

1. [Kubernetes API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.11/#-strong-read-operations-pod-v1-core-strong-)
2. [serviceaccount](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/)